# Aborting a web service call from the server side

Tags: web-services, jetty

We have a web service where sometimes the clients are stuck in a loop and are harassing the server, using up threads and causing high CPU. We would like to force the client to hit a timeout, but not use a thread in our thread pool (by sleeping, for example). We're using Jetty to supply the web services:

```
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor102.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at com.sun.xml.ws.api.server.InstanceResolver$1.invoke(InstanceResolver.java:250)
at com.sun.xml.ws.server.InvokerTube$2.invoke(InvokerTube.java:149)
at com.sun.xml.ws.server.sei.SEIInvokerTube.processRequest(SEIInvokerTube.java:88)
at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.__doRun(Fiber.java:1063)
at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber._doRun(Fiber.java:979)
at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.doRun(Fiber.java:950)
at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.runSync(Fiber.java:825)
at com.sun.xml.ws.server.WSEndpointImpl$2.process(WSEndpointImpl.java:380)
at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter$HttpToolkit.handle(HttpAdapter.java:651)
at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter.handle(HttpAdapter.java:264)
at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.ServletAdapter.invokeAsync(ServletAdapter.java:218)
at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletDelegate.doGet(WSServletDelegate.java:159)
at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletDelegate.doPost(WSServletDelegate.java:194)
at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServlet.doPost(WSServlet.java:80)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:769)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:585)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:577)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:223)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1125)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:515)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1059)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:215)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:110)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.DebugHandler.handle(DebugHandler.java:81)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:485)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:290)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:248)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:540)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:606)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:535)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Any way to have the web server abort the work but NOT return any response to the client?

UPDATE: For clarification - we control ONLY the server. We do not control the clients.

Answer (score 0):

You may find this [link](https://jaibeermalik.wordpress.com/2013/10/09/tipstricks-how-to-set-web-service-client-request-timeout-value/) informative!

Comment: We don't control the client, we control the server.